# neo4j MERGE, SET, CASE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to do a tricky query. 
I need to check to see if a relationship exists;

- if it does I need to set a property (prop) on that relationship to max(0, prop + val)
- if it does not I need to create it set the property to max(0,value)

The property can be go negative.

Here's essentially what I'm going for, though this format won't work because you can't have a WITH statement after a MERGE:

```
MATCH (n1:Type1 {id:{id1}), (n2:Type2 {id: {id2}) 
MERGE (n1)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(n2) WITH CASE 
WHEN r.prop + {val} < 0 THEN 0 
ELSE r.prop + {val} END as prop 
ON CREATE SET r.prop = prop
ON MATCH SET r.prop = prop
```

This is how it would look it two parts, though I'd like to not have to query twice:

```
MATCH (n1:Type1 {id:{id1}), (n2:Type2 {id: {id2}) 
MERGE (n1)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(n2)
ON CREATE SET r.prop = 0

MATCH (n1:Type1 {id:{id1})-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->n2:Type2 {id: {id2})
WITH r, CASE 
WHEN r.prop + {val} < 0 THEN 0 
ELSE r.prop + {val} END as prop
SET r.prop = prop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH (n1:Type1 {id:{id1}), (n2:Type2 {id: {id2}) 
MERGE (n1)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(n2)
ON CREATE SET r.prop = 
CASE
    WHEN {val} < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE {val}
    END
ON MATCH SET r.prop = 
CASE 
   WHEN r.prop + {val} < 0 
   THEN 0 
   ELSE r.prop + {val} 
   END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this query should do the trick :

```
MATCH (n1:Type1 {id:{id1}), (n2:Type2 {id: {id2}) 
MERGE (n1)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(n2)
ON CREATE SET r.prop = 0
ON MATCH SET r.prop = 
CASE r.prop 
   WHEN r.prop + {val} < 0 
   THEN 0 
   ELSE r.prop + {val} 
   END
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not work. It's not catching the case when r.prop + {val} < 0 and it needs to set r.prop to {val} or 0 on CREATE as well